# Compiling einstein sums optimally

Tags: optimization, matrices

Einstein summation is a convenient way to express tensor operations which has found its way in tensor libraries like numpy, torch, tensorflow, etc.

Its flexibility lets us represent the product of three matrices, $X$, $Y$, $Z$  of dimensions $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$, $(c,d)$ as

```
X.Y.Z = einsum('ab,bc,cd->ad',X,Y,Z)
```

However, the above compiles to something like

```
for a_ in range(a):
  for d_ in range(d):
     res[a_,d_] = 0
     for b_ in range(b):
        for c_ in range(c):
           res[a_,d_] += X[a_,b_] * Y[b_,c_] * Z[c_, d_]
```

This native is quadratic in the size of the matrices when simply doing

```
einsum('ac,cd->ad',einsum('ab,bc'->'ac', X, Y), Z)
```

Would be merely cubic.

There are roughly three levels of optimization we can imagine a smarter implementation of `einsum` to perform.

1. Decompose an einsum of tensors $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ into an einsum of pairs of tensors $x_1, x_2$, $e(x_1, x_2), x_3$, etc to optimize computation time.
2. Rely on associativity (where applicable) to pick those pairs judiciously (this is a classic dynamic programming problem) and construct the appropriate intermediary tensors.
3. Discover Strassen-like formulas for the specific tensor computation

While 3 seems clearly out of reach, 1 and 2 seem like they could be achievable exactly with a reasonably straightforward algorithm. Are such algorithms known for generic einstein summations? Have they been studied?

Comment: What does the notation `cd->ab` mean?

Comment: The quote inserted was a typo, it's `ab,cd->ad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the general problem of finding the optimal contraction order is NP-hard [1]. A recent paper on approximately optimizing the contraction order, and containing relevant references, is [2].

[1] Chi-Chung, Lam, P. Sadayappan, and Rephael Wenger. "On optimizing a class of multi-dimensional loops with reduction for parallel execution." Parallel Processing Letters 7.02 (1997): 157-168.

[2] Schindler, Frank, and Adam Jermyn. "Algorithms for tensor network contraction ordering." Machine Learning: Science and Technology (2020).

Comment: Thank you, "tensor network contraction" is the keyword I was missing

Comment: Not all evaluation strategies are contractions though. The naive product of 3 $n \times n$ matrices in $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$ time doesn't happen if you follow *any* one of the two contraction strategy... yet, you'll see numpy's einsum for instance run it in quadratic time anyway. What gives?

Comment: By quadratic, do you actually mean *quartic* (${\cal O}(n^4)$)? I guess that any *optimal* evaluation strategies would consist of contractions.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant to write quartic. And the answer to my question is that, yes, this is a thing, but there's a flag...
https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Specifically I was thinking: the paper assumes that contractions always dominate naive evaluation, but surely if that were the case, numpy's einsum would implement at least a naive contraction. Turn out it does, but only with a flag.